# Does nn.Transformer in PyTorch include the PositionalEncoding() process so far?

Tags: pytorch, python-3.8, transformer-model

I was trying to solve a seq2seq problem with Transformer Module. According my understanding to the source code from [pytoch's github](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/transformer.py), I thought PositionalEncoding() is not yet included. (Correct me if i'm wrong). But I saw soooo many codes (including the one written by one of my tutors) using the default nn.Transformer to model seq2seq problems which really confused me.

Comment: it doesn't seem that there is an official Pytorch module for positional encoding but you can copy it from the docs [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transformer_tutorial.html), scroll down a bit then you'll see it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. And I also notice that other Positional Encoding methods such as [t2v](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.05321.pdf) are gaining popularity in recent years.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is positional encoding necessary for transformer in language modeling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61440281/is-positional-encoding-necessary-for-transformer-in-language-modeling)